# Splitting arguments

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to split the member mention (message) and the reason (args) but it fails to do so: I have it getting both the mention and the reason but it mentions the member and puts the reason under the reason field on the embed.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "kick",
  guildOnly: true,
  nsfw: false,
  description: "Kick a member from the server with or without a reason.",
  execute(message, args) {
    if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
      return message.channel.send("You need to mention a member to     kick.");
    } else {
      const member = message.mentions.members.first();
      const reason = args;
      const kickEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("#ff00ea")
        .setAuthor("User Kicked")
        .setDescription(member.displayName + " was removed from the server.")
        .addField("Assigned by", message.author.username, true)
        .addField("Reason", reason, true);
      member.kick(reason);
      message.channel.send(kickEmbed);
      message.react("")
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you explain better what  the problem  is?

Comment: That command works fine however, for the reason it is linking the member and the reason together. The member mention is stored in the message part of the execute and the args is the reason. The embed is linking both, the message and the args to the kick reason

Comment: Can you  console.log the args and show it's output?

Comment: Member: !kick <USERNAME> Kicked. Reason: <USERNAME>,Kicked.

I don't want the reason to contain the contents of message which is the user

Code: console.log("Member: " + message + " Reason: " + args)

Comment: Then to  remove the reason from the args, do something like  reason = args.split(',')[1]

Comment: I have tried that, it just shows “args.split is not a function”

Comment: can  you console.log(typeof args)

Comment: That’s what comes up in the console.

Comment: What comes in  the console when you do this? console.log(typeof args)

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2e61dd19947f26c75760a68cfbcd3460
https://gyazo.com/b34684527dd7e46f1eb8446861ec8d61

Comment: console.log( typeof(args) ) not split

Comment: https://gyazo.com/30e6a57f44830c8906ba5c90e6559628 https://gyazo.com/81bd860cbd4618f48cc76b2df9c69320

Comment: Remove the  args.split(,)[1] and  put it back to args

Comment: Like this? https://gyazo.com/45834f67d73056c9899d007bb469fc4e

Comment: No, like  how you  have it in the example above.

Comment: Got it back to that.

Comment: Then now check what the  console.log will print on the console

Comment: Using typeof, it returns "object"

Comment: try reason  = args[1]

Comment: Yep, that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` is an array, the first index contains the user and the second index contains the reason in your case.

So this should work, it depends on your input.

```js
reason = args[1]
```